# how to get the cell header text by clicking a span inside it's column cell using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wan to get the cell header name of column by clicking on any cell of that header's column as like below image and here i will have a class to a span 

this is my HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>         
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>        
            <td><span class="abc"></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td><span class="abc"></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>       
           <td><span class="abc"></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

can any one help with this?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to assign a click handler to each table cell and keeping track of the column number the click happened in. Then you could use the column number to read the text of the `<th>` element in that column.

```
var table = document.querySelector('table'),
    rows = table.rows

for(var r=0; r<rows.length; r++) {
  var cells = rows[r].querySelectorAll('td')
  for(var c=0; c<cells.length; c++) {
    (function(col) {
      cells[col].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(rows[0].querySelectorAll('th')[col].textContent) 
      })
    })(c)
  }
}
```

[Here is a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/avgp/prwrjxo6/)

Comment: thanks,it is working fine,
but what if i want to display header in alert by clicking only those cells who has a '<span class="abc"></span>' tag

Comment: Then you use the DOM methods to traverse into that element.